# Solution of Hilbert Space operator equation

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

The probelm I am trying to solve is the following:

Given:
$X$, $Y$ are two Hilbert spaces. $T: X \to Y$ is a linear bounded operator, and the composite operator $TT^* :Y \to Y$ is invertible.

Question:
Show that $x_1 := T^*(T T^*)^{-1}y$ is one solution of the operator equation $Tx = y$, for any $y \notin R(T)$

The way I have proceeded to solve this is by simply substituting $x_1$ into the equation $Tx = y$ and then having $TT^*$ cancel out. My question is what is the significance of $y \notin R(T)$? Would $y$ not have to be in the range in order for this to be a valid solution? Or have I solved it in an incorrect manner? Thank you

Comment: Some is wrong. If $y\not\in R(T)$, by definition you cannot have $y=Tx$.

Comment: Maybe the book meant $y\in R(T)$, but had a typo?

Comment: Assuming that there is a typo, would the approach I have taken be the correct way of approaching this problem? Because as far as I am aware, if $y \notin R(T)$ , then $x_1$ cannot be a solution.